# Rails FormTagHelper missing important select and collection_select methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-helpers

You can do this when you use `form_for(@model...)`:

```
collection_select(:subscription, :duration, ["Some", "Values"], :to_s, :to_s, {:prompt => true})
```

And the output is something like this:

```
<select id="subscription_duration" name="subscription[duration]">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="Some">Some</option>
    <option value="Values">Values</option>
</select>
```

If you use a form *without* a model, you don't have that nice helper method to create the `<option>` tags for you.  Instead, you have to do this:

```
select_tag("subscription", '<option value="Some">Some</option><option value="Values">Values</option>')
```

FormHelper and [FormOptionsHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html) work together on a *form wrapping a model*, and they have the [`select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M001624) and [`collection_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M001625) to make life easy.  For a plain `form_tag` (without a model), however, there is no such FormOptionsTagHelper.  [FormTagHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html) has a [`select_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#M001730) method, but you have to manually write out the options which is a waste.  It seems like this has been fixed somewhere.

I could write my own helper to get rid of writing those option tags manually, but thats what `FormOptionsHelper#collection_select` does...  Is there an equivalent out there for forms without models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**select** and **collection_select** can be called without a model. I usually use a combination of two significant words, and an array of pairs [label, value] to select. The only drawback is having to use the format abc[xyz].

You tried to use [options_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M001627)?

```
select_tag 'Account', options_for_select({ "Basic" => "$20", "Plus" => "$40" }, "$40")
```